# Why isn't the "crab" (an entity) touchable like the "monster" (also an entity)?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm developing a game and I was wondering why isn't the "crab" (an entity) killable like the "monster" (also an entity). What I mean is that if I touch the goblin monster, I get a point, but I just walk across the crab.
I attempted to add an if..else, but then the player got thousands of points per second.
What have I done wrong?

```js
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function() {
  bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/background.png";

// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function() {
  heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/hero.png";

// Monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function() {
  monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "images/monster.png";

// Crab image
var crabReady = false;
var crabImage = new Image();
crabImage.onload = function() {
  crabReady = true;
};
crabImage.src = "images/old/hero.png";

// Game objects
var hero = {
  speed: 300 // movement in pixels per second
};
var monster = {};
var crab = {};
var monstersCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player catches a monster
var reset = function() {
  hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
  hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

  // Throw the monster somewhere on the screen randomly
  monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
  monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));

  // Throw the crab somewhere on the screen randomly
  crab.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
  crab.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
};

// Update game objects
var update = function(modifier) {
  if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
    hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
  }
  if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
    hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
  }
  if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
    hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
  }
  if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
    hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
  }

  // Are they touching?
  if (
    hero.x <= (monster.x + 32) && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32) && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32) && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)
  ) {
    ++monstersCaught;
    reset();
  }
};

// Draw everything
var render = function() {
  if (bgReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
  }

  if (heroReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
  }

  if (monsterReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
  }

  if (crabReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(crabImage, crab.x, crab.y);
  }

  // Score
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
  ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillText("Mobs killed: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32);
};

// The main game loop
var main = function() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var delta = now - then;

  update(delta / 1000);
  render();

  then = now;

  // Request to do this again ASAP
  requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

// Let's play this game!
var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Underbound</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="game">
   <script src="js/game.js"></script>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `update()` function doesn't pay any attention to the crabs when it checks for "touch".

Comment: I added an else for crabs, but then the player, as I said, gained thousands of points within seconds.

Comment: If you don't post the code that doesn't work, nobody can tell you *why* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're only checking if the hero collides with `monster`.

```
hero.x <= (monster.x + 32) && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32) && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32) && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)
```

Instead, you should probably create a function for checking if they collide:

```
function isColliding(a, b) {
  return a.x <= (b.x + 32) && b.x <= (a.x + 32) &&
         a.y <= (b.y + 32) && b.y <= (a.y + 32);
}

if (isColliding(hero, monster)) { ...
```

Then use also check if they collide with `crab`.

```
if (isColliding(hero, crab)) { ...
```

It'd be more sustainable (until you have a whole lot of monsters) if you put all of your "monsters" into an array then check against each monster in the array.

As for the issue with gaining lots of points quickly: you have to remove the monster (or crab) from the play area and stop checking for collisions during the `update` phase or the player will continue to collide with the crab and gain points.

One solution for this would be to give your monsters an `active` (or similar property). By default, this will be true but when the player collides with them, this will be false. Then you will only draw them and check for collisions if `active` is true.

Comment: Should I leave `a, b` in `function isColliding(a, b)`?

Comment: @svalis Sure or name it whatever you want. They're just parameter names. They can be anything you want. `a` and `b` just makes sense to me.